# LINQ syntax error in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am not familiar with VB and just converted my code online from C# to VB !

```
m_sDir = New [String](m_sDir.Where(Function(c) (c >= 50) AndAlso (c <= 112)).ToArray())
```

but compiler is saying it can't do comparison between character and integer. 
So how should I update that code above?

Comment: `m_sDir` almost has to be a string since it is assigned back to the same var.  String do not contain integers, so the `c` tests are invalid.  Might helo to describe *what* you are trying to do.

Comment: 50 and 112 are ASCII values , basically trying not to use RegEx and still only accept characters from that string that are in that range

Comment: You can use [`Asc(c)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.asc?view=netframework-4.7) to convert the characters to the ASCII values, or use the character comparison [suggested by Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45337238/2278086).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converter appears to have changed character literals to integers for some reason. `"X"c` is the character literal syntax in VB.NET.

```
m_sDir = New String(m_sDir.Where(Function (c) c >= "2"c AndAlso c <= "p"c).ToArray)
```

Comment: 50 and 112 are ASCII values , basically trying not to use RegEx and still only accept characters from that string that are in that range.

Comment: @KSNoob: Okay, well, `"2"c` and `"p"c` are the decoded ASCII character literals.